# Moshiach and three meals

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, meal-seudah, maseches-shabbos

The Gemara in [*Shabbos* 118a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118a.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> Rabbi Shimon ben Pazi said that Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said in the name of bar Kappara: Anyone who fulfills the obligation **to eat three meals on Shabbat is rescued** from three punishments: **From the pangs of the Messiah**, i.e., the suffering that precedes the advent of Messiah [...]

1. Why specifically 3 meals?
2. Is the Gemara saying that one who specifically eats the third meal will be saved from the "birth pains" of Moshiach or is this only one who eats all three meals?

Comment: I don't understand 3. How can you eat a third meal without eating three meals?

Comment: I also don't understand Q 3. The Gemarah says "three meals", not "the 3rd meal". Wait! Was this question edited b/c u originally had two items as #2?

Answer (score 2):

[The Imrei Emes](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/155988/p/92/t/0.90699024140559151234/fs/9U8uch2AaAIPBraFObwPTX8YNyKgA6uBwrdn2XcTp7Yp/start/3240/end/3288/c) [(Avraham Mordechai Alter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Mordechai_Alter) explains this Gemara as follows (No time for a translation, anyone who can do this, please feel free to translate it. Otherwise I will pick this up at a later time):

> כל המקיים שלש סעודות בשבת ניצול משלש פורעניות וכוי הלשון מקיים אינו מדוקדק לכאורה דהול"ל האוכל שלש סעודות וכוי ונראה דלשון מקיים פירושו כמ"ש המקיים בכלאים לוקה דפירש רש"י שעשה להם סייג וגדר כי בשבת צריך לעשות גדר לכל ששת ימי המעשה שמחמת זה הגדר לא תוכל שום מחשבה רעה לעלות על לבו וזה הפירוש כל המקיים שלש סעודות בשבת שבשבת אפשר לתקן זה וכשמתקנין זה ניצולים מכל הדברים הרעים

Similary, the [Maharsha (Chidushei Agadot)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/23377/p/85/t/0.90699024140559151234/fs/9U8uch2AaAIPBraFObwPTX8YNyKgA6uBwrdn2XcTp7Yp/start/272/end/288/c) on this Gemara explains:

> אמיתת יום השבת כאשר פורעניות מחבלו של משיח הוא מצד עצמו כי יום ומדינה
> של גיהגמ וממלחמת השבת כאשר נחלק גוג ומגוג לחלקיו יש בו ג' זמנים
> מחולקים ולמעלה אמרו כי המקיים ג' סעודת ניצול מג' פורענות חבלו של משיח
> מלחמות גוג מגוג דינו של גהנם ומפרש כי אלו ג' נקראים יום כמו שמבואר
> למעלה ור"ל כי אלו ג' נקראים יום כי היום בא על עצם הזמן ואין היום דבר
> מקרי אבל היום הוא עצם המציאות ועצם הבריאה שהרי בבריאה נאמר ויהי ערב
> ויהי בוקר יום אחד הרי לך כי עצם המציאות תולה ביום וכאשר יהי' דבר
> פורענות שהוא בעצם ואינו במקרה כמו רוב הפורענות שהם בעולם שהם במקרה מצד
> החטא ואלו ג' פורענות הם בעצם ש כך הם מששת ימי בראשית נגזרו אליו ג'
> פורענות לכך נקראו כל אחד ואחד יום ואמר כי הזהיר בג' סעודת של עונג שבת
> שנקראים כל אחד ואחד יום שמורה על עצם יום השבת שיש בו ג' חלקים שהם עונג
> וטוב כי זה היום אינו לשאר

[Rabbi Yaakov Montrose from Kollel Iyun Hadaf of Yerushalayim](https://dafyomi.co.il/discuss_daf.php?gid=2&sid=20&daf=118&n=2) explains this Maharsha as follows:

> The MAHARSHA explains that these three things are the three major events (or in case of Gehinnom, a place) during which sins are atoned for by punishment before the time when there will be eternal reward for the righteous. We know that the Gemara often compares the afterlife, where the righteous will be rewarded, to Shabbos. It is therefore fitting, the Maharsha explains, that if someone fulfills the commandment to enjoy Shabbos, he will be spared (measure for measure) from the three great difficulties before the "real Shabbos" that you mention above.

So, the Maharsha is saying that if we were to observe the Seudah Shelishit (the three meals on Shabbos), we infuse such joy that we are being spared from Chevlei Moshiach.

The [Zohar HaKadosh](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.288b.11?vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains the significanse of the "three meals" and why it has to be three.

> אָמַר רִבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן, אַסְהַדְנָא עָלַי לְכָל אִלֵּין דְּהָכָא, דְּהָא מִן יוֹמָאי לָא בָּטִילְנָא אִלֵּין ג' סְעוּדָתֵי, וּבְגִינֵיהוֹן לָא אִצְטְרִיכְנָא לְתַעֲנִיתָא בְּשַׁבְּתָא. וַאֲפִילּוּ בְּיוֹמֵי אַחֲרִינֵי לָא אִצְטְרִיכְנָא, כָּל שֶׁכֵּן בְּשַׁבְּתָא. דְּמַאן דְּזָכֵי בְּהוּ, זָכֵי לִמְהֵימְנוּתָא שְׁלֵימָתָא. חַד, סְעוּדָתָא דְּמַטְרוֹנִיתָא. וְחַד, סְעוּדָתָא דְּמַלְכָּא קַדִּישָׁא. וְחַד, סְעוּדָתָא דְּעַתִּיקָא קַדִּישָׁא, סְתִימָא דְּכָל סְתִימִין. וּבְהַהוּא עָלְמָא יִזְכֵּי בְּהוּ לְאִלֵּין. הַאי רָצוֹן כַּד אִתְגַלְיָיא, כָּל דִּינִין אִתְכַּפְיָין מִשּׁוּלְשְׁלֵיהוֹן.
> 12
> תִּקּוּנָא דְּעַתִּיקָא קַדִּישָׁא אִתְתְּקַן בְּתִקּוּנָא חַד, כְּלָלָא דְּכָל תִּקּוּנִין. וְהִיא חָכְמָה עִלָּאָה, סְתִימָאָה. כְּלָלָא דְּכָל שְׁאָר, וְהַאי אִקְרֵי עֵדֶן עִלָּאָה סְתִימָא. וְהוּא מוֹחָא דְּעַתִּיקָא קַדִּישָׁא. וְהַאי מוֹחָא אִתְפְּשַׁט לְכָל עִיבָר, מִנֵּיהּ אִתְפְּשַׁט עֵדֶן אַחֲרָא. וּמֵהַאי עֵדֶן אִתְגְּלַף.

> Rabbi Shimon says that he never messed three Shabbat meals all his life. Those who have the merit of three meals, ears the complete faith, which is closer connection to the Shechina. The first meal of Shabbat connects to the ‘queen’, which is the Shechina in Malchut because the night is under the control of Malchut.
> The second meal at the morning of Shabbat connects to the light of the concealed wisdom from the Atika Kadisha. The morning prayers of Shabbat connect to Zeir Anpin that elevates to Atika Kadisha in the afternoon, the time of the third meal.
> The Second meal is called the meal of Atika Kadisha and the third meal is called for the name of Zeir Anpin.
> As Zeir Anpin ascend to Atika Kadisha, the ‘forehead’/‘will’ of the Keter is revealed and judgments have no control during Shabbat.

> Translation taken from: [DAILY ZOHAR # 2542 – HA’AZINU – THREE MEALS OF LIGHT](https://dailyzohar.com/daily-zohar-2542/)

Similary, the Zohar, commenting on Shemos 31:17 [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.17?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Zohar.2.88b.5&vhe2=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang2=bi):

> בִּסְעוּדָתָא תְּלִיתָאָה דְּשַׁבְּתָא, כְּתִיב וְהַאֲכַלְתִּיךָ נַחֲלַת יַעֲקֹב אָבִיךָ. דָּא הִיא סְעוּדָתָא דִּזְעֵיר אַפִּין, דְּהַוֵי בִּשְׁלֵימוּתָא. וְכֻלְּהוּ שִׁיתָא יוֹמִין, מֵהַהוּא שְׁלִימוּ מִתְבָּרְכָן. וּבָעֵי בַּר נָשׁ לְמֶחדֵי בִּסְעוּדָתֵיהּ, וּלְאַשְׁלְמָא אִלֵּין סְעוּדָתֵי, דְּאִינּוּן סְעוּדָתֵי מְהֵימָנוּתָא שְׁלֵימָתָא, דְּזַרְעָא קַדִּישָׁא דְּיִשְׂרָאֵל, דִּי מְהֵימָנוּתָא עִלָּאָה, דְּהָא דִּילְהוֹן הִיא, וְלָא דְּעַמִּין עוֹבְדֵי עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים וּמַזָּלוֹת. וּבְגִינִי כַּךְ אָמַר, (שמות ל״א:י״ז) בֵּינִי וּבֵין בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל.

Rabbi Eliezer Melamed in his [Peninei Halakhah](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118a.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Peninei_Halakhah%2C_Shabbat.7.1.2&ven2=Peninei_Halakhah,_English_ed._Yeshivat_Har_Bracha&vhe2=Peninei_Halakhah,_Yeshivat_Har_Bracha&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) explains:

> “Whoever delights in Shabbat is spared from imperial subjugation” (ibid. 118b). Informing these statements is the idea that without Shabbat we would become totally subjugated to the material burden of this world. We would work nonstop in order to sustain our bodies and provide them with pleasure; we would forget our divine souls and find it difficult to elevate ourselves toward divine ideals. Our spiritual inclinations would be suppressed and silenced, and we would consequently sink into all the world’s faults and perversions, which are the cause of all calamity. But when one is privileged to connect to Shabbat with all his being, spiritual and material, through Torah study and prayer as well as rest and pleasure, he transcends the world’s flaws and reaches the eternally good world. Thus he is automatically saved from the calamities of this world.

It seems to me that the explanation of the Peninei Halakhah is similair to what the Imrei Emes writes (as described above).

You ask if this Gemara only applies to one who eats the third meal, or one who eats all three meals. The Zohar seems to be saying that it is *one who eats all three meals*. Since, "Those who have the merit of three meals, earns the complete faith".